# How to pass Mongoose validation errors in Postman response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

If I enter more than or less than 10 digit number in the `phone` number field in the postman I get the validation error message in the terminal and the server get crashes but I want to get that error message in postman JSON. how to do that?

schema.js

```
const { json } = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const SomeModelSchema = new Schema({
phone: {
type: Number,
required:true,
unique: true,
validate: {
  validator: (val) => {
      var re = /^\d{10}$/;
      return (!val ) || re.test(val)
  },
  message: 'Provided phone number is invalid.'
  },
},
module.exports = mongoose.model("SomeModel", SomeModelSchema);
```

Post method

```
router.post("/admin/add_profile", async (req, res) => {

try {
  const send = new SomeModel({ 
    phone: req.body.phone,
  });
  send.save();
 
res.json({
    responseMessage: "Everything worked as expected",
  });
} catch (error) {
  res.status(400).send(err.message);
}
});
```

error message in the terminal but I need to display the error message like `phone number is invalid` in the postman response
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `await` your `save()` call. Otherwise the call continues to run, but it will never reach the catch-block, since the error was thrown asynchronously in your promise.

This is also the reason why your whole app crashes and does not catch this error.

This means that just using `await send.save();` should resolve the issue.
After that your catch block will be processed. Unfortunately you catch errors in the variable named `error`, but you try to read the message from the variable named `err`, which still needs to be corrected.

Comment: is there any way to print the custom error message like `10 digit number is required rather than that catch error